# React import error - Element type is invalid: expected a string or class/function

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and don't understand this error I am getting: 
[image]

Here's the render method for my menu:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar color="faded" light expand="md">
                    <NavbarBrand href="/">Nomad Press</NavbarBrand>
                    <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink tag={Link} to="/Home">Home</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">Github</NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                                    Options
                                </DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu >
                                    <DropdownItem>
                                        Option 1
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                    <DropdownItem>
                                        Option 2
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                    <DropdownItem divider />
                                    <DropdownItem>
                                        Reset
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                </DropdownMenu>
                            </UncontrolledDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                    </Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }

I double checked my imports and made sure the packages were installed. I don't see anything wrong with my render method.
```

Here's what my imports are for menu:

```
import React from 'react';
...
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I get the following error when I remove the brackets around `Link`.
[image] 
Any ideas?

EDIT ----

Here's my react versions:

```
"react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
"react": "^16.2.0",
```

It left out my imports for Navlink in the sample code due to the restrictions on stackoverflow. I am importing that correctly.

I am using [real-world react](https://github.com/gothinkster/react-redux-realworld-example-app) sample on github as a reference.

EDIT 2 -------
Here are my imports for App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import Home from './Home';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './Menu'
```

Comment: what is the react version yo are using? and react router

Comment: You probably intended to import `NavLink` instead of link

Comment: `when I remove the brackets around Link ` Link is named export  and u r importing correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You have two way imports somewhere.

If moduleA imports moduleB, and moduleB imports moduleA, one of them will be "undefined", and to prevent this, don't use React.

> > I get the following error when I remove the brackets around Link.

You shouldn't do this, { Link } should be in brackets, cause it's exported with name "export { Link }", not as "export default Link" inside react-router-dom. Problem not with it, perhaps your "Menu" is undefined because it's dependent with other module, which is stored in "App".

Finalize: App have some module "moduleA", and Menu is using "moduleA", when you try to import "moduleA" inside of your menu, it should be working independently from "App" module, check this.

When I use modules folder, like "modules" with list of every single one inside, inner modules cannot call "modules" => child module, to be able use this, use full path to every single module, like import something from "modules/something". Check your dependencies

Comment: I don't have two way imports anywhere in my app. App imports menu but menu does not import app. There's no circular dependencies in my app.

Comment: Do you have line "export default Menu;" in Menu.jsx? Try to print it with console.log before export in Menu.jsx, and after import in App.jsx, what they shows?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Print what to the console? I do export default in menu.js.

Comment: Print body of exporting object (which have to be function) before "export" in menu.js, and after "import" in app.js to see, in which moment it's losing object reference.

Comment: Why do you say don't use React with regards to imports?

Comment: I didn't say "don't use React", all I said, is that you need to debug, when that happens that function (react component is a function) becomes to undefined. When you print before export and after import - you will see, that possibly console.log of object before export will be not printed, and that means - you're trying to initialize module, which is unable to init, because have something broken in relation between files.